# Codeigniter: error 400 where sending file to server using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm trynig to send file (input type file) to php server using ajax.
the file is sent to the controller in codeigniter but i get 400 response ( Bad request ). How can i fix this problem ?

Here is the code:

```
<form id="load_file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="content-group">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Default file input</label>
        <input id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
                <button id="upload">Upload</button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
$('#upload').on('click', function(e) {
    var base = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
    e.preventDefault();
    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    //alert(form_data);                             
    $.ajax({
        url: 'importa/process', // point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
            alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

it's not a path problem beacause when i delete type: 'post' it's working but in controller when i try to display file name i got error message undefined index file

Comment: console the baseurl then see what you got..

Comment: it's not a path problem beacause when i delete `type: 'post'` i can access to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a security issue ( CSRF Proctection in Codeigniter ).
We should add csrf_token to data before sending it:

```
form_data.append('csrf_token_name', 'token');
```

or disable CSRF Proctection from config file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead base url use `site_url()`

```
var site_url = '<?php echo site_url('process/index');?>';
```

and now

```
 $.ajax({
    url: site_url,
  ....
```

Assuming that you have enabled `url` helper in `config.php` and you have a controller `Process` with `index` method

Comment: it's not a path problem beacause when i delete  `type: 'post' ` it's working but in controller when i try to display file name i got error message `undefined index file`

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a relative path with the ajax call:

```
url: '/controller/function'
```

Comment: it's not a path problem beacause when i delete  `type: 'post' ` it's working but in controller when i try to display file name i got error message` undefined index file`

Comment: can you see anything in your controller with `print_r($_POST);die();`?

Comment: it's an empty array. it seems like the fonction can't intercept the POST

Comment: seems like you are not sending your data correctly, you could check with `console.dir(form_data)` instead of your `alert(form_data)`

Comment: here is the result with console.dir(form_data) 
FormData
__proto__: FormData
append: ƒ append()
delete: ƒ delete()
entries: ƒ entries()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
get: ƒ ()
getAll: ƒ getAll()
has: ƒ has()
keys: ƒ keys()
set: ƒ ()
values: ƒ values()
constructor: ƒ FormData()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FormData"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a file like this

You can give your whole form to `FormData()` for processing

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

And in the controller check the file input with `$_FILES` not `$_GET` or `$_POST`

```
print_r($_FILES['sortpic']);
```

Comment: i did it but i get this error message: `form_data0 is not defined`

Comment: It's a URL issue.

Comment: when i delete `type: 'post'` i can access controller

Comment: Try to give URL like this `url: "<?= base_url('process')?>"` and put `data: form_data` right after the URL

Answer (score 0):

Define AJAX like this

```
<script>
$('#upload').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var base = '<?php echo base_url();?>';       
    $.ajax({
        url: base + 'process', 
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Your URL says `base + 'process'` it means your calling index function of the  `process` controller. And make sure your base URL in `config.php` ends with a forward slash(`/`) (`https://stackoverflow.com/`). So URL should look like this

`https://stackoverflow.com/process` <-- In here you didn't specify function name. so make sure in your controller `index()` function is added.